# How to use tooltip in django dropdownlist form

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, django-forms

I have a django dropdown list in the django form in forms.py

Fruits= [
('orange', 'Oranges'),
('cantaloupe', 'Cantaloupes'),
('mango', 'Mangoes'),
('honeydew', 'Honeydews'),
]

fruits = forms.CharField(label='Fruits', widget=forms.Select(choices=Fruits))

i want to make it such that whenever I hover to any of the list it needs to show a description of that particular fruit. For instance: For orange: it is orange, for apple: it is apple and so on.

How would I accomplish that? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

The option tag has only 'value' attribute, but I would need 'data-toggle: tooltip' and the title attribute.

Comment: The question needs community edit.

Comment: Try to add javascript to your tags that might be usefull.this is more related to that.